# Wildcards: how do I list files ending in `.txt` only without using the dot character?

Tags: shell, files, wildcards

I have a directory with nine files in it.

- 1 ending in `.bat`
- 2 ending in `.bak`
- 4 ending in `.txt`
- 2 ending in `.xtxt`

My question is, how do i list only the files ending in `.txt`, but without using the period. So I want to display the 4 ending in `.txt`, without using the command

```
ls *.txt
```

because I don't want to use the period to filter out the files. I'm learning wildcards at the moment so they are used in this. I think I have to use the `!` command somehow but I'm unsure where to use it.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean "I don't want to use the period to filter out the files"?  Why doesn't `*.txt` work for you?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want bot the files ending in .txt and .xtxt?

Comment: You don't want to use the *period*, or you don't want to use the *asterisk*.  Sounds to me like you don't want to use the second one.

Comment: If you want to list all `.txt` and `.xtxt` files, just do `ls *txt`.

Comment: @don_crissti -  I think the unclear part is why he doesn't want to use the period in *.txt, which is the obvious way to get the list of files he's looking for -- if he can state what problem he's trying to solve, then maybe someone can give him the answer. There are lots of ways to list only the files ending in .txt without using a '.' in the glob match, but some may not meet his needs in other ways.

Comment: @don_crissti the question is the unclear part about the question.

Comment: @don_crissti - Even knowing that his problem set is limited to the given set of files would be useful, but few real-world problems are so well defined that the entire input space is known and can be enumerated in a few items. Questions here are supposed to be [based on real problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), not open-ended questions that could spawn dozens of answers. There are 4 answers below that work with the file set above, but without further information, it's not clear if any of them meet his needs.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand *why* you don't want to use `.`. Anyway you can use some character class instead where `.` is included, but other chars from your directory not, good candidate for this purpose can be `[[:punct:]]`:

```
LC_ALL=C ls -- *[[:punct:]]txt
```

I changed locale to `C` as character classes depend on that, and added `--` to `ls` option in order to list all files which start with `-` properly.

---

<sub>Definition:</sub>

```
`[:punct:]'
     Punctuation characters; in the `C' locale and ASCII character
     encoding, this is `! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \
     ] ^ _ ` { | } ~'.
```

Comment: The part `LC_ALL=C` does not have the intended effect because it affects only the process `ls` but the path expansion is performed by the shell where the original value of `LC_ALL` stays unchanged. --- The easiest way of doing what you intended is to start a subshell and set the variable in its scope using a separate assignment command (notice the semicolon): `( LC_ALL=C ; ls -- *[[:punct:]]txt )` The subshell ensures that the original state of `LC_ALL` does not change.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Bash shell:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(*xtxt|*bak|*bat)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `[!x]txt` to list all files ending in `txt` but exclude the ones ending in `xtxt`:

```
ls ./*[!x]txt
```

(you may have to turn off history expansion in your shell if you get an `event not found`)
or use ASCII code for dot, e.g.:

```
ls ./*$'\x2E'txt
```

or

```
ls ./*$'\056'txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Extremely ugly, since this could be achieved using `find . -type f -name "*.txt"` easily, but if you don't want to put an `.` in there, and the only file extensions you are going to find in that directory are `.bat`, `.bak`, `.txt`, and `.xtxt`, then you can try this:

```
ls *txt | grep -v "xtxt$"
```

`ls *txt` will bring anything ending with `txt`, and `grep -v "xtxt$"` will prevent to show in the results anything that ends in `xtxt`.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the more common answer to your exercise would be `ls *[^x]txt`.

I'm surprised that `[!x]` works equally well.  I'm used to `!` being for bash history completion, and causing weird problems because it's still a special character inside double quotes, so I just try to avoid it!

```
# echo 1
1
# !echo
echo 1
1
# "!echo"
echo 1
1
# echo "the!echo"
echo theecho 1
theecho 1
```

I was aware it's used for logical negation in `test` conditions (`[ ! $condition ]`), like C.  The nice thing about using `^` is it's the same in regular expressions: `ls | grep [^x]txt$`.  (The `$` "anchors" the pattern to the end of the line).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is based on a misunderstanding. The dot has a special meaning in full regular expressions: It means any character. But filename expansion in the shell uses "globs", a much simpler pattern language in which the dot has no special meaning at all. So you can use it safely:

```
% touch foo.txt foomtxt
% ls
foo.txt
foomtxt
% ls *.txt
foo.txt
```